# Is there a way in IDWC 9.4 to set defaults for job attributes

Tags: workload-scheduler

Adding multiple jobs for a number of zCentric agents (all JSR352 jobs). Is there a way to set defaults for Connections attributes in IDWC (Eg, hostname, username, password), to reduce effort to add jobs.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to specify the values in variable tables and use variables in the job you define in DWC.

At the following link you can find the official documentation about using variable from DWC in job type with advanced option (that includes also the JSR352)
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSRULV_9.3.0/com.ibm.tivoli.itws.doc_9.3/zos/src_man/eqqr1addvarondwc.htm